# What is the difference between this 2 'IF'?

Tags: php

Given this:

```
$ids = '';
```

I just realized that this:

```
$single = $ids == FALSE || is_array($ids)? FALSE : TRUE;
var_dump($single);
```

and this:

```
if ($ids == FALSE) 
{
    $single = TRUE;     
}
else 
{
    if (is_array($ids)) 
    {
        $single = FALSE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $single = TRUE;
    }
}
var_dump($single);
```

Display different results (false and true respectively). However, This only happens when the variable is:

```
$ids = '';
```

or

```
$ids;
```

If $ids is an array, an integer, or a string it works fine.
**Does anybody know why?** Thanks in advance!

By the way, I have just realized that if you type $ids === FALSE in the first conditional stament (the single line one) it will work fine. But I still don't understand the 'logic' behind this.

Comment: i.e. http://codepad.org/zue3hIoK

Comment: Get out of the habit of describing things as "working fine". It requires an assumption as to what "working fine" means, that may not be correct. Instead, _describe behaviours_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot parentheses:

```
$single = (($ids == FALSE) || (is_array($ids)? FALSE : TRUE));
var_dump($single);

// Output: true
```

### [Live demo](http://codepad.org/zjaVQI9z).

Without them, precedence [gives you a result different from that which you were expecting](http://codepad.org/HL9PeNe3):

```
<?php
$id = '';

$single =  $ids ==  FALSE ||  is_array($ids)? FALSE : TRUE;
//        (        (                        )             )
//                   FALSE                    FALSE

var_dump($single); // False


$single = (($ids == FALSE) || (is_array($ids)? FALSE : TRUE));
//              TRUE       ||       FALSE

var_dump($single); // True
?>
```

---

<sup>Note that `'' == FALSE` is `true`; I'm not sure whether you realised that.</sup>

Comment: And even better would be: `$single = $ids == FALSE || !is_array($ids);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I get it... it is always that little details that gives me a headache :)

Comment: See my comments at @Juhana's answer. The expression is evaluated differently.

Comment: By the way LR0, that is one of the best answers I have ever got in Stackoverflow. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

The order of operations is different in the two examples. The first one is parsed as:

```
$single = ( $ids == FALSE || is_array($ids) ) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

The second one is equal to:

```
$single = ( $ids == FALSE ) || ( is_array($ids)? FALSE : TRUE );
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first one is not: `($ids == FALSE ||  is_array($ids)) ? FALSE : TRUE`?

Comment: According to the [precedence table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) `||` is stronger than `? :`.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but It may be because you are returning a Boolean Equivlenant (1 / 0) or a True and False String. If you want Absolute equality try using 3 equals symbols.